# Tinting the Keyboard InputAccessoryView of a UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, inputaccessoryview

I've got a `UIWebView` in the app I'm currently working on. It looks fine on `iOS7` but in `iOS6`, I'm getting an ugly tint on the in-built `inputAccessoryView` when the user gives a textfield focus... [Show this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLKhQ.jpg)

Is anyone aware of where I can set the tint here? The `UIWebView` in `Interface Builder` does give me a tint option but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any insight as to how `iOS` decides upon the tint color to use here would be interesting too.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm trying to do the same currently.